# Reloading only Div using Ajax with rails

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ajax, refresh

Through my table (id = "portfolios"), on clicking on a cel, I am sending the value to my rails controller /game/search.

This query is working fine, but the entire page is getting reloaded. I want only the table to be reloaded. Is there any way to do so?

```
function getval(cel) {


    if (isNaN(cel)==true){

          window.alert("Oops! Click again.");

        }
        else {
          c="<% cut_line %>";


jQuery.ajax({
            data: 'q=' + cel,
            //dataType: 'script',
            type: 'post',
            url: "/game/search"      
          });
          //post_to_url("/game/search", {q: cel});

        }
    }
```

This is the controller action:

```
def search
Game.new.update_matrix(params[:q], Ip.where(ip: request.remote_ip).last)
redirect_to :action => :play
end
```

Comment: can you paste your controller action?

Answer (score 0):

To fix your problem you need to add into your controller action

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html
  format.json {render json: object}
end
```

Your url that you pass to ajax should have the `.json` extension or if you don't want that, set in the routes file the resource to `defaults: {format: 'json'}`.